# Why is there a delay that omits part of my code from running before page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, chatbot

I'm coding userscript in tampermonkey for a chat box, to make a bot. When the page loads, this code runs, but the problem is that the page reloads before it finishes submitting the text.

```
document.getElementById("customchattext").value = "HB's ChatBot: Congrats!";

function send() {
setTimeout(function(){ document.forms[0].submit(); location.reload(); }, 3000);
}

window.onload = send();
```

How can I put a delay on the reload specifically to occur after the form submits?

Comment: First, you have to make sure your form submit doesn't already load a new page (since it usually does) probably by switching to an ajax call.  Second, you seem to already know that you use `setTimeout()` to schedule code to run after a delay.

Comment: If you have the control of the submit destination page, move the location.reload() inside it.

Comment: I do not have control, that's why I'm making a userscript for it.